# navbar sticky not working correctly in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have navbar menu. I have added some javascript code to make this navbar sticky while the user scrolls the page. The problem is that when the user is scrolling the page its like before itself. It's not making the navbar sticky.

Can anyone please tell me what could be wrong with my code, any help would be great.

This is my code :

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  seeFunction()
};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("thor");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function seeFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="thor" class="ttm-header-wrap">
  <!-- ttm-stickable-header-w -->
  <div id="ttm-stickable-header-w" class="ttm-stickable-header-w clearfix">
    <div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
      <div class="site-header-menu-inner ttm-stickable-header">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- site-branding -->
          <div class="site-branding">
            <a class="home-link" href="index.html" title="Planwey" rel="home">
              <img id="logo-img" class="img-center" src="TEIA png big.png" alt="logo-img">
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- site-branding end -->

          <div id="site-navigation" class="site-navigation">
            <div class="ttm-menu-toggle">
              <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle-form" />
              <label for="menu-toggle-form" class="ttm-menu-toggle-block">
<span class="toggle-block toggle-blocks-1"></span>
 <span class="toggle-block toggle-blocks-2"></span>
 <span class="toggle-block toggle-blocks-3"></span>
 </label>
            </div>
            <nav id="menu" class="menu">
              <ul id="modify" class="dropdown">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                  <ul>
                    li><a href="about-us.html">TEIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-1.html">Board Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-2.html">Agenda</a></li>
                <li><a href="our-event.html">Vision & Mission</a></li>

                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a>
                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Type</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Benefits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Register/Join</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Previous Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="single-blog.html">Press Release</a></li>
                    <li><a href="single-blog.html">Gallery</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="nyan" style="background-color: #00bfff; color: white !important; "><a href="#">Log In</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="sss"><a href="admin">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="members">Member</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <!-- site-navigation end-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i had an in built sticky and on scroll shrink js code, i removed it because i didnt want the navbar to shrink, its like below:

```html
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( matchMedia( 'only screen and (min-width: 1200px)' ).matches ) 
    {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 30 ) {
            $('.ttm-stickable-header').addClass('fixed-header');
            $('.ttm-stickable-header').addClass('visible-title');
        }
        else {

            $('.ttm-stickable-header').removeClass('fixed-header');
            $('ttm-stickable-header').removeClass('visible-title');
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: You've added the 'jQuery' tag to the question, but are not using it. Does this mean you are looking for jQuery solutions to the problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if anyone can help me with jquery or js for this solution it wud be fine

Comment: add your css code here

Comment: @LaljiTadhani i have added some js which the template already had and which i had to remove

Comment: `fixed-header` or `sticky` CSS Properties?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: @LaljiTadhani i thought both were same, i just want the navbar to stay there itself while scrolling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198721/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-kingkhan-kkhan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of js use css `position: sticky`

```css
#thor {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

*source: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)*

Comment: its not working, and when i used it, while scrolling the whole nav menu dissappears

Comment: post your css in question and we will help you find out why

Comment: i have posted an old js which worked, but i didnt want the shrink functionality, can you please check it

Comment: in this [pen](https://codepen.io/ciekals11/pen/OJLjVBQ) is all you gave and there it works

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS

```
.sticky{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("thor");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
header.classList.add("sticky");
} else {
header.classList.remove("sticky");
}
}
```

```css
.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="thor">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  
</div>
```